# Show more than 5000 records from CRM in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to understand how FetchXml works (or any other method) because I want to retrieve and process more than the limit of 5000 records that CRM returns on the api call below.

My base url looks like this: `http://crm.domain.com:1234/api/data/v8.0/`

the resource is: `emails`

and query options are: `$top=50000&$filter=description ne null and not contains(sender, '@not-interesting.com')`

I'm trying to copy the code from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327917(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

but I'm having issues with creating the `OrganizationServiceProxy` object like this:

```
var creds = new ClientCredentials();
creds.UserName.UserName = CrmApiUsername;
creds.UserName.Password = CrmApiPassword;

using (var _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
            new Uri(CrmApiBaseAddress), null, creds, null))
        {
            // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
            _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes(); // ...
```

I'm getting an error:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://crm.domain.com:1234/data/v8.0/?wsdl&sdkversion=90'.'
>   WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: When you open the url in a browser - what does it show?

Comment: @user2190035 same error:
Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
but this is because for some reason OrganizationServiceProxy is trying to add "?wsdl&sdkversion=90" to the url.

Comment: and it is skipping the /api/ part.

Comment: From the sample url you mention it looks like you are connecting to a on-premise instance, right? Check [Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt608055(v=crm.8)) as a primer - I'll post a working example later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up these two:

1. Web API - which was available after v8.0
2. 2011 endpoint - which is deprecated now but was available for really long time

[Read more](https://joshimandarblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/09/web-api-in-dynamics-crm-2016-what-you-should-know-msdyncrm/)

When you [use web api](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/01/querying-data-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2016-using-web-api/) the url will be like: `https://yourcrm.crm#.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/`

In case of [Organization Service Proxy](https://carldesouza.com/connecting-dynamics-365-organization-service-proxy/) still the 2011 endpoint: `https://yourcrm.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`

For breaking the 5000 records limitation & getting more than 5k records, the pagination concept has to be used. [How to fetch more than 5000 entities from CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755536/7920473)

For more ideas, I have answered in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545988/7920473) about other options.